Storybook with Next.js and Webpack 5 cannot resolve various node modules
I'm trying to create a Storybook project with Next.js and webpack 5. I have a few decorators in my preview.tsx:
import type { Preview } from "@storybook/react";
import React from "react";
import { EtechUiProvider } from "etech-ui-utils";

const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/i
      }
    }
  }
};

export const decorators = [
  (Story) => (
    <EtechUiProvider configPath="./etech.config.ts" options={{ filter: "etech-ui-utils-tests" }}>
      <Story />
    </EtechUiProvider>
  )
];

export default preview;


The code of these isn't too important but what is important to know is it does use some dynamic imports to load certain server dependencies when the code runs on the server.
When I use this configuration with Vite and Storybook I have no problems. However, with Next.js and Webpack 5 I get several errors:
ERROR in ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/testbinary.js 9:11-35
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/ekrich/projects/etech-ui/node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib'
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./testbinary.js ./testbinary
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 86:13-36 291:36-53
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/bcrypt@5.1.1_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js 3:17-48
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/universal-fs@2.0.0-canary-4_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/universal-fs/index.js 2:0-28 47:41-56 54:41-56 64:52-67 67:46-61 134:37-53
 @ ../../../packages/etech-ui-utils/dist/index.js 7:0-44 58:22-26 66:39-45 116:22-28
 @ ./.storybook/preview.tsx 5:0-49 17:35-50
 @ ./storybook-config-entry.js 11:2321-2406 32:0-35:2 32:2308-35:1

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js 9:11-35
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/ekrich/projects/etech-ui/node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util'
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./util/compile.js ./util/compile
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 86:13-36 291:36-53
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/bcrypt@5.1.1_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js 3:17-48
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/universal-fs@2.0.0-canary-4_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/universal-fs/index.js 2:0-28 47:41-56 54:41-56 64:52-67 67:46-61 134:37-53
 @ ../../../packages/etech-ui-utils/dist/index.js 7:0-44 58:22-26 66:39-45 116:22-28
 @ ./.storybook/preview.tsx 5:0-49 17:35-50
 @ ./storybook-config-entry.js 11:2321-2406 32:0-35:2 32:2308-35:1

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <!doctype html>
| <html>
| <head>
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 86:13-36 291:36-53
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/bcrypt@5.1.1_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js 3:17-48
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/universal-fs@2.0.0-canary-4_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/universal-fs/index.js 2:0-28 47:41-56 54:41-56 64:52-67 67:46-61 134:37-53
 @ ../../../packages/etech-ui-utils/dist/index.js 7:0-44 58:22-26 66:39-45 116:22-28
 @ ./.storybook/preview.tsx 5:0-49 17:35-50
 @ ./storybook-config-entry.js 11:2321-2406 32:0-35:2 32:2308-35:1

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@ngrok+ngrok-darwin-arm64@1.4.1/node_modules/@ngrok/ngrok-darwin-arm64/ngrok.darwin-arm64.node 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@ngrok+ngrok@1.4.1/node_modules/@ngrok/ngrok/index.js 141:28-64
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/universal-fs@2.0.0-canary-4_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/universal-fs/index.js 166:32-54
 @ ../../../packages/etech-ui-utils/dist/index.js 7:0-44 58:22-26 66:39-45 116:22-28
 @ ./.storybook/preview.tsx 5:0-49 17:35-50
 @ ./storybook-config-entry.js 11:2321-2406 32:0-35:2 32:2308-35:1

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@ngrok+ngrok-darwin-universal@1.4.1/node_modules/@ngrok/ngrok-darwin-universal/ngrok.darwin-universal.node 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@ngrok+ngrok@1.4.1/node_modules/@ngrok/ngrok/index.js 116:24-64
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/universal-fs@2.0.0-canary-4_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/universal-fs/index.js 166:32-54
 @ ../../../packages/etech-ui-utils/dist/index.js 7:0-44 58:22-26 66:39-45 116:22-28
 @ ./.storybook/preview.tsx 5:0-49 17:35-50
 @ ./storybook-config-entry.js 11:2321-2406 32:0-35:2 32:2308-35:1

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/detect-libc@2.0.3/node_modules/detect-libc/lib/detect-libc.js 6:21-45
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/ekrich/projects/etech-ui/node_modules/.pnpm/detect-libc@2.0.3/node_modules/detect-libc/lib'
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js 8:20-42
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js 4:19-55
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 56:11-40
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/bcrypt@5.1.1_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js 3:17-48
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/universal-fs@2.0.0-canary-4_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/universal-fs/index.js 2:0-28 47:41-56 54:41-56 64:52-67 67:46-61 134:37-53
 @ ../../../packages/etech-ui-utils/dist/index.js 7:0-44 58:22-26 66:39-45 116:22-28
 @ ./.storybook/preview.tsx 5:0-49 17:35-50
 @ ./storybook-config-entry.js 11:2321-2406 32:0-35:2 32:2308-35:1

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/https-proxy-agent@5.0.1/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js 16:30-44
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/Users/ekrich/projects/etech-ui/node_modules/.pnpm/https-proxy-agent@5.0.1/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist'
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/https-proxy-agent@5.0.1/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/index.js 5:32-50
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/install.js 59:23-51
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./install.js ./install
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 86:13-36 291:36-53
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/bcrypt@5.1.1_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js 3:17-48
 @ ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/universal-fs@2.0.0-canary-4_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/universal-fs/index.js 2:0-28 47:41-56 54:41-56 64:52-67 67:46-61 134:37-53
 @ ../../../packages/etech-ui-utils/dist/index.js 7:0-44 58:22-26 66:39-45 116:22-28
 @ ./.storybook/preview.tsx 5:0-49 17:35-50
 @ ./storybook-config-entry.js 11:2321-2406 32:0-35:2 32:2308-35:1

Here is my next.config.mjs file:
/** @type {import("next").NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  // Storybook config
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = {
      fs: false,
      assert: false,
      buffer: false,
      console: false,
      constants: false,
      crypto: false,
      domain: false,
      events: false,
      http: false,
      https: false,
      os: false,
      path: false,
      punycode: false,
      process: false,
      querystring: false,
      stream: false,
      string_decoder: false,
      sys: false,
      timers: false,
      tty: false,
      url: false,
      util: false,
      vm: false,
      zlib: false,
      tls: false,
      ngrok: false,
      "child_process": false,
    };
    return config;
  }
};

As you can see I have tried setting each affected packages resolve to false however that does nothing.
I have also tried installing the packages, also no luck. Something that is a potential problem is that the .next folder is being created outside of this projects root directory(I'm in an NX monorepo). However, cding into this project and then running still does resolve the issue.
Here is my package.json:
{
  "name": "next",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@chromatic-com/storybook": "2.0.2",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^8.3.1",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "8.3.1",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "8.3.1",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "8.3.1",
    "@storybook/blocks": "8.3.1",
    "@storybook/nextjs": "8.3.1",
    "@storybook/react": "8.3.1",
    "@storybook/test": "8.3.1",
    "@types/webpack": "^5.28.5",
    "babel-core": "6.26.3",
    "storybook": "8.3.1",
    "webpack": "5.94.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "etech-ui-utils": "link:/Users/ekrich/git/etech-ui/packages/etech-ui-utils",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "next": "14.2.12",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  }
}


Here is my tsconfig.json:
    "extends": "../../../tsconfig.react.json",
    "include": ["../../../packages/**/stories/*.stories.tsx"],
    "exclude": ["../../../packages/etech-ui-utils/scripts/**"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": ["@types/node", "vite/client"]
    }
}

I have also tried setting the root directory in my tsconfig but still no luck. What can I do to fix or dismiss these errors. Or better yet can I just use Next.js with turbopack instead webpack.
